# Deployment Error on save from Developer Console

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console, error

I noticed that I cannot save orupdate any code from the Developer Console (Apex Classes, Visualforce...). When I try to save a file, I get an error similar to this one:

> An unexpected error has occurred. `1307199800-3660` (`-1595400218`) for `deploymentId=1drS00000004lmFIAQ` If this persists, please contact customer support.

Also, the tab is still displaying `Saving: [my-component-name]`.

Any known problem or should I contact support directly?

Comment: On the "Progress" panel, click "Cancel All Deployments" and try to save again. Does it still give you the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the Deployment ID in your clipboard, and head to:

`https://[INS].salesforce.com/[PUT-DEPLOYMENT-ID]`

Click on the `Delete` button to delete the deployment record, and everything should be back to normal.

*Source: [Failed to create deployment: This container has a save in progress with deploymentId=[YOUR-DEPLOYMENT-ID]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20775/failed-to-create-deployment-this-container-has-a-save-in-progress-with-deployme)*

Comment: Having the same issue. When I try to head to that link, I end up with a `URL No Longer Exists`.

Answer (score 5):

1307199800-3660 (-1595400218) Is a GACK number, this generally means you have an error with salesforce itself.

The first part of this is the time stamp, the second part is the error code.
(Think that is the right way round)

If it continues i would contact salesforce

Comment: Close. Neither is actually a time stamp. The first part is the GACK ID, but both should be given when submitting a case.