# Developer Console : Failed to create createContainerMember for containerId

Tags: apex, class, developer-console, contentworkspace

Unfortunately, I get the following error while try to save changes to a class,

> Failed to create createContainerMember for containerId=1dc19000000BE6AAAW: This container member belongs to a container that currently has an unfinished save request with deploymentId=1dr19000000e9gQ. You may not modify any members in this container until it completes.: Metadata Container ID

I tried the solution mentioned here [Developer console cannot save classes/triggers/pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204953&language=en_US) though it worked for the first time and then the trick stopped working.

Anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Try going to the the Progress Tab in the Developer Console and click on Cancel all deployments. This worked for me.

[Failed to create deployment: This container has a save in progress with deploymentId=[YOUR-DEPLOYMENT-ID]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20775/failed-to-create-deployment-this-container-has-a-save-in-progress-with-deployme)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new Developer Console workspace.
From the Developer Console, select Workspace > New Workspace.
Enter a name for your new workspace, and then click OK.

Delete your corrupted workspace:
 a.  From the Developer Console, select Workspace > Workspace Manager.
 b.  Highlight your corrupted workspace.
 c. Click Delete

Comment: Thanks. I also just closed the developer console with the file unsaved, reloaded it and then was able to save that way.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It was happening because of a recent **system refresh**. My previous profile got changed due to it hence I lost access. So, please check if there have been any recent changes in your User.
Also, Please check if you have sufficient privilege to make changes.