# Deployment Error on save from Developer Console - recurring error message with new ID

Tags: deployment, developer-console

While trying to save in the developer console, I get the following error:

**Deployment Error**

[image]

I have followed both solutions at:

- Cancel all deployment from the progress window from:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/20837/260

and

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/20777/260

  `https://[INS].salesforce.com/[PUT-DEPLOYMENT-ID]` and click the delete button

However, neither work.

Each time I do a save, I get the same error, with a new ID

Progress log looks like this:

- You can see I tried 2 times to save

[image]

p.s.
There is nothing in the SF debug logs.

I am able to edit the same class outside the developer console (e.g. from within SF sandbox GUI. and than reload the file in console (see the edit) , edit and save, and I get the same error.

Comment: Could the issue be with the Apex class you are trying to save? What if you try editing the same record outside of the developer console?

Comment: I am able to edit the same class outside the developer console (e.g. from within SF sandbox GUI. and than reload the file in console (see the edit) , edit and save, and I get the same error.

Comment: Unless there is anything special about the apex class your best option would be to raise a support case with Salesforce. That is can save via the simpler web UI suggests a bug with the tooling or metadata API.

Comment: That error means something went wrong inside of Salesforce, so filing a case would be good regardless of a workaround. Out of curiosity, what if you create and switch to a new workspace?

Comment: @Thomas - apparently it's a known issue with a workaround. a new workspace solved it https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4QhAAK go ahead submit as answer so I can accept

Comment: Great, glad you found a known issue. I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error means something went wrong inside of Salesforce. This turned out to be an upgrade error on old workspaces. To resolve the issue, follow the steps as outlined in the [known issue](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4QhAAK):

Create a new workspace in developer console:

- Workspace / New Workspace

Then switch to the newly created workspace:

- Workspace / Switch Workspace / {the new space}

You will be able to save once you are in the new workspace.