# Error saving classes

Tags: apex, class

When trying to save these two clases highlighted in the photo, you are encountering the error "Invalid api version: 0.0" as highlighted in the image.
[image]

Comment: Please see this issue that answers a similar question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132138/invalid-api-version-0-0-preventing-me-from-saving-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the classes from Salesforce UI instead of developer console.
Goto Salesforce Org -> Setup -> Quick Find Box -> Apex Classes -> click on the new button and try creating from there. If these are existing classes find these classes, and Edit them.

Comment: Thanks, it worked